# Autolayout using anchors not laying out my views the way I intended?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

So I have a fairly simple cell view that I am trying to customize. I have a bunch of fields and label that I would like to layout as shown in the below image

[image]

However what I end up with using the constraints I have setup looks something like this...

**indexLabelBackground** (circle)

**indexLabel** (number)

**repsField** (0 the left of REPS)

**repsLabel** (REPS string)

**dividerLabel** ("/" string)

**weightField** (0 to the left of POUNDS)

**weightLabel** (POUNDS string)

[image]

I have looked at my constraints over and over again and I can't find anything that would lead me to think my constraints are wrong so Im hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help me identify this puzzling problem...

**P.S.** I even created a new project and attempted to recreate this layout using storyboards using the same constraints which seemed to look good.

```
private func setupViews() {
    addSubview(indexLabelBackground)
    indexLabelBackground.addSubview(indexLabel)
    addSubview(repsField)
    addSubview(repsLabel)
    addSubview(dividerLabel)
    addSubview(weightField)
    addSubview(weightLabel)

    indexLabelBackground.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true
    indexLabelBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24).isActive = true

    indexLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indexLabelBackground.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    indexLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indexLabelBackground.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    repsField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indexLabelBackground.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    repsField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: repsLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    repsField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    repsLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dividerLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    repsLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    dividerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dividerLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    weightField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dividerLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    weightField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weightLabel.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    weightField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    weightLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    weightLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
//  weightLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true //note this fixes the problem but forces my label to be a fixed width
    }
```

So something to note is that if you look at the last line, this can be "fixed" in a hacky way such as adding a width constraint to the weightLabel. However I'd like to avoid this as it seems hacky and unnecessary with the right constraints.

Comment: Why don't you use Storyboard for this ?

Comment: it would make more sense if you were to annotate the image to represent which view in your code refers to which view in the image.

Comment: there are a couple reasons why for this project but yea... I would like this to be done programmatically :(

Comment: you are right sorry about that, made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple elements (fields and labels) in your cell that can be stretched to make the layout work, and you haven't told *Auto Layout* which ones not to stretch.

You want your labels to stick to their *intrinsic content size* (be as big as they need to be to show the text, but no bigger).  You specify this by setting a high *content hugging priority*.  By default, when you programmatically create `UITextField`s and `UILabel`s, their *content hugging priority* is *low* (`250`).  Since they are all low, *Auto Layout* will stretch them in some unknown order to make the layout work.

I suggest adding these 3 lines to set the *content hugging priority* to *high* `(750)` for your 3 labels:

```
repsLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
dividerLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
weightLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

That way, your labels will always be the size needed to hold their text, and they can then *anchor* your layout (pun intended).

> I even created a new project and attempted to recreate this layout
>   using storyboards using the same constraints which seemed to look
>   good.

In the *Storyboard*, `UILabel`s have a higher default *content hugging priority* (`251`) than `UITextFields` (`250`), so it *just works*.  It beats me why they chose to give them all *low* (`250`) when created programmatically.

Comment: dudeeeee! thank you for the awesome explaination! never did figure out content hugging priority but now I totally get it

Comment: Rock Solid explanation. this saved my time a lot.

Comment: @Badrinath, I'm glad it helped you.  Please throw me an upvote to let other people know the answer is useful.

Comment: Sure will do , Also how can i handle the same to autoadjust the view vertically ? 

Say I have a CreditCard view which has below items

    1. **Image ( left ) -> Title
    2. Description
    3. More Details button**
    
some times description gets more and hides More Details Button , can i set like below 

    `self.creditCardDetailView.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)`

Comment: @Badrinath, please post your question as a new question with full details of the code you’ve tried, the result you are getting, and what you expect. Asking a new question in the comments deprives you of getting help from the full SO community and deprives others from benefitting from the Q and A.

Comment: @vacawama can you help me on below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917487/how-to-compress-extra-padding-at-the-top-and-bottom-of-the-uilabel